# Creating a series of graphs in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have a series of three similar graphs that I would like to show in a single window in R..

This is the data:

```
Date Tank Time Female.in.Middle Female.in.R.assoc Female.in.L.assoc R.side.of.divider
117 25-Jun   I3  200           0.0966            0.2721            0.2001            0.0000
120 26-Jun   I3 1030           0.2118            0.5663            0.2212            0.0000
123 27-Jun   I3  200           0.0000            0.0000            0.0000            0.0000
128 28-Jun   I3 1100           0.0237            0.0672            0.1408            0.3289
129 28-Jun   I3  230           0.0683            0.0606            0.2488            0.0000
132 29-Jun   I3  200           0.1823            0.1180            0.6990            0.0000
135  2-Jul   I3  200           0.0000            0.0000            0.0000            0.0000
138  3-Jul   I3 1030           0.0000            0.0000            0.0000            0.0000
    L.side.of.Divider Tank.1 Date.Entered M.L.name Male.L.Length Male.L.Weight M.R.name
117            0.4285     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
120            0.0000     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
123            0.9961     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
128            0.4423     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
129            0.6215     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
132            0.0000     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
135            0.9952     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
138            0.9948     I3       22-Jun  green 2           7.6         14.32   pink 1
    Male.R.Length Male.R.Weight Side.of.Spawn F.Length F.Weight F.name last.female.spawn.date
117           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
120           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
123           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
128           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
129           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
132           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
135           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
138           7.7         14.79             L      5.5     5.64     2c                 22-Jun
    spawn.date.in.paradigm  X d.in.p dbs X.1 X.2 X.3
117                  3-Jul 11      3   8  NA  NA  NA
120                  3-Jul 11      4   7  NA  NA  NA
123                  3-Jul 11      5   6  NA  NA  NA
128                  3-Jul 11      6   5  NA  NA  NA
129                  3-Jul 11      6   5  NA  NA  NA
132                  3-Jul 11      7   4  NA  NA  NA
135                  3-Jul 11     10   1  NA  NA  NA
138                  3-Jul 11     11   0  NA  NA  NA
```

And I am using this code to make the graphs:

```
d2c<-plot(jd2c$d.in.p, jd2c$L.side.of.Divider, type='l', col='purple', xlab='Days After Entry', ylab='Proportion of Time Spent on Each Side of Divider', main='Female 2c', ylim=c(0,1))
legend('topleft',.8,c('Left', 'Right'),pch=c(.8), col=c('purple','green'))
points(jd2c$d.in.p, jd2c$R.side.of.divider, type='l', col='green')


az2c<-plot(jd2c$d.in.p, jd2c$Female.in.L.assoc, type='l', col='purple', xlab='Days After Entry', ylab='Proportion of Time Spent in Assoc. Zones', main='Female 2c', ylim=c(0,1))
legend('topleft',.8,c('Left', 'Right'),pch=c(.8), col=c('purple','green'))
points(jd2c$d.in.p, jd2c$Female.in.R.assoc, type='l', col='green')


rside2c<-cbind(jd2c$Female.in.R.assoc + jd2c$R.side.of.divider)
lside2c<-cbind(jd2c$Female.in.L.assoc + jd2c$L.side.of.Divider)

side2c<-plot(jd2c$d.in.p, lside2c, type='l', col='purple', xlab='Days After Entry', ylab='Proportion of Time Spent on Each Side (cumulative)', main='Female 2c', ylim=c(0,1))
legend('topleft',.8,c('Left', 'Right'),pch=c(.8), col=c('purple','green'))
points(jd2c$d.in.p, rside2c, type='l', col='green')
```

How can I get all three graphs to show up on one window?

Thank you!

Comment: This is where `ggplot2` really shines.

Comment: to be bit more specific, have a look at `ggplot2` facets: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_wrap.html.

Comment: except that ggplot2 also requires reshaping all of the data as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `par`:

```
# Put this before your plots:
par(mfrow=c(3,1))  # your plots appear in one column, three rows,
                   # in one figure.
plot(...)
plot(...)
plot(...)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # always a good idea to return it to how it was
                   # afterwards, so later plots aren't affected
```

Comment: This works well except for that the graphs seem either stretched or condensed depending on wether I use mfrow=c(3, 1) or mfrow=c(1, 3).....      Is there code to get the graphs in the same scale as if there were only one per window?

Comment: You can change the shape of the graphs just by stretching or shrinking the window. Try altering the shape of the graph window before you save the graph.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear how you'd like the three graphs to appear but a simple solution is to preface your graphing with...

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
```

Now you'll see all three graphs in one window.  You'll need to make the window wider of course.  Otherwise the graphs will be all squished.  You'll need to look up `?Devices` for the particular output you want.  If you just want it to appear on screen then `X11` on Linux or `quartz` on Mac OS X will work.  For example, on a Mac call...

```
quartz('my new graph', 15, 5)
```

That will make a space to draw in 3x as wide as it is high.  It's automatically implicitly called with dimensions of 7" whenever you make an initial plot call.

You should probably look up `par` in help.  It's also good advice to save the current settings and then restore them later.  So, before graphing use...

```
opar <- par(mfrow = c(1,3))
```

and then after your graphing

```
par(opar)
```

That's an easy way to restore things even after you've made many changes to the graphing parameters.

Comment: The quarts() function works for what I am looking for but when I try to pdf() my graph, it says 'file damaged' when I attempt to open the file..     Can I set the window to that size and then run the code to pdf all my graphs to one place?

Comment: you have to close the pdf with dev.off()

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned `par` with `mfrow`, you can also use the `layout` function if you want more control over the position, size, and shape of the plotting regions.